next js internationalization and auth
I have a problem in setting up route middleware and internationalization in next js and laravel . I want to do is that if there is no token , user can not go other page by typing from url .So I added middleware . But that's showing as like this  .
This is my middleware code .
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { isPathStartsWithBackSlash } from "./app/utils/checkUrlTypes";
import createMiddleware from "next-intl/middleware";

const locales = ["en", "mm", "jp"];
const defaultLocale = "mm";
const i18nMiddleware = createMiddleware({ locales, defaultLocale });

export function middleware(request) {
  const pathName = request.nextUrl.pathname;
  console.log("pathName", pathName);
  // Internationalization logic (using next-intl)
  i18nMiddleware(request); // Execute internationalization middleware first

  // Authentication logic
  if (isPathStartsWithBackSlash(pathName)) {
    const cookies = request.headers.get("cookie");
    const hasCookie = cookies && cookies.includes("IncomeController");
    if (!hasCookie) {
      console.log("no cookie");
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/404", request.url));
    }
  }

  // Continue with the default behavior
  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/", "/(mm|jp|en)/:path*"],
};


If I changed this code , the route is worked . But cannot protect route by typing from Url.
//TODO ADD route middleware for internationalization
import createMiddleware from "next-intl/middleware";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

let locales = ["en", "mm", "jp"];

const middleware = createMiddleware({
  // Add locales you want in the app
  locales: ["en", "mm", "jp"],

  // Default locale if no match
  defaultLocale: "mm",
});

export default middleware;

export const config = {
  // Match only internationalized pathnames
  matcher: ["/", "/(mm|jp|en)/:path*"],
};


This is my next js folder structure

This is layout.jsx

Please kindly help me . I took 1 week for this and still counting. Thank you for your time.
This works also . But cannot do internationalization.
middleware.jsx
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { isPathStartsWithBackSlash } from './libs/checkUrlTypes'

export function middleware(request) {
  const pathName = request.nextUrl.pathname

  // Check if the requested URL matches a protected route
  if (isPathStartsWithBackSlash(pathName)) {
    // Check if the cookie exists in the request headers
    const cookies = request.headers.get('cookie');
    const hasCookie = cookies && cookies.includes('IncomeController');
    if (!hasCookie) {
      // If the cookie is not present, redirect to the unauthorized page
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/404', request.url));
    }
  }
  // If the request doesn't match a protected route or the user is authenticated, continue with the default behavior
  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/:path*'],
};


I got with this . If you have same problem , please reference this
Gist Link
config.js
export const locales = ["mm", "en", "jp"];

export const defaultLocale = "mm";

i18n-config.js
export const i18n = {

locales: ["mm", "en", "jp"],
  defaultLocale: "mm",
};

export const I18nConfig = i18n;

export const Locale = I18nConfig["locales"];

i18n.js
import { notFound } from "next/navigation";
import { getRequestConfig } from "next-intl/server";
import enMessages from "../messages/en.json";
import mmMessages from "../messages/mm.json";
import jpMessages from "../messages/jp.json";

const messages = {
  en: enMessages,
  mm: mmMessages,
  jp: jpMessages,
};

export default getRequestConfig(async ({ locale }) => {
  if (!(locale in messages)) notFound();

  return {
    messages: messages[locale],
  };
});

